# puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha NOT SOLVING CAPTCHAS PROPERLY

Tags: puppeteer

Im having an issue solving captchas using puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plgin-recaptcha. Everything was going very smooth and randomly it broke. It is definitely some issue with not returning the captcha token but im not sure how to fix it. Here is some info.

**This is my code initializing it**

```code
puppeteer.use(
  RecaptchaPlugin({
    provider: {
      id: '2captcha',
      token: 'token' // REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR OWN 2CAPTCHA API KEY ⚡
    },
    visualFeedback: true // colorize reCAPTCHAs (violet = detected, green = solved)
  })
)
```

**This is where i call it**

`await page.solveRecaptchas()`

**This is the error**

```code
PuppeteerExtraPluginRecaptcha: An error occured during "getRecaptchaSolutions": {
  _vendor: 'recaptcha',
  provider: '2captcha',
  id: '97j1ixpkm2h',
  requestAt: 2021-07-24T17:26:54.251Z,
  error: 'Error: 2captcha error: Missing response data: undefined'
}
```

**If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.**